# Python argparse prevent long and short flags at same time

Tags: python, argparse

I have this code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-L', '--list', action='store_true', help='list options')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I want this:

```
$./example.py --list
```

or

```
$./example.py -L
```

but not:

```
$./example -L --list # or --list -L
```

Is there an elegant way to avoid that both flags being used at the same time?

Comment: And what if they were? How would that be a problem?

Comment: Just as a matter of form

Comment: Do your own parsing of `sys.argv` if you don't like the latitude `argparse` provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can form a mutually exclusive group. That isn't ideal, since you'll end up repeating arguments to each, but that can be wrapped up into a helper function if need be.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

arg_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
arg_group.add_argument('-L', action='store_true', help='list options')
arg_group.add_argument('--list', action='store_true', help='list options')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

If you wanted to pretty this up a bit (to avoid repeating yourself), you could do something like:

```py
class MutexArgParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def add_mutex_arguments(self, flags, *args, **kwargs):
        arg_group = self.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        for flag in flags:
            arg_group.add_argument(flag, *args, **kwargs)

parser = MutexArgParser()
parser.add_mutex_arguments(['-L', '--list'], action='store_true', help='list options')
args = parser.parse_args()
```